# Unable to save store preferences in Eclipse (Using wrong Directory?)

Tags: eclipse

Recently my shortcut keys stopped working. Whenever I try to change them in Window -> Preferences -> Keys and save I get this error:

```
'Store preferences' has encountered a problem.
AN internal error occurred during: "Store preferences"
Details:
An internal error occurred during: "Store preferences".
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\bestg\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.oomph.setup\workspace.setup (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

However this path is not the right path, this is an path I have on another on another windows installation I have on this PC (not a different user, different drive/OS).  The path should be `C:\Users\brick\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\`

I tried creating a shortcut to the right area in a folder I made 'C:\Users\bestg' but this did not work. I have also tried both switching workspaces inside eclipse and manually setting the workspace through eclipse.ini:

```
-Dosgi.instance.area.default="C:\Users\brick\eclipse-workspace"
```

and config.ini

```
osgi.instance.area.default="C:\Users\brick\eclipse-workspace"
```

However I am still getting this error when trying to save my shortcuts and can not use my shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem multiple times on my Mac computer using Eclipse whenever I migrate my workspace to a new computer.
The issue is with the Oomph Preference Recorder trying to record preferences to a directory that does not exist.
The solution that worked for me is to go into Eclipse Preferences -> Oomph -> Setup Tasks -> Preference Recorder, and set the 'Record into' field to wherever on your computer you want to store preferences. For me, it had auto-populated options for either the Eclipse installation directory or my current workspace.
After making this change, saving preferences should start working again.